# $f: R^{m} \rightarrow R^{n}$ be defined $ f(x)=B \cdot x+b $ where $B$ is an $n$ by $m$ matrix, and $b \in R^{n}$. Show $f$ is differentiable at $a.$

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus

**Definition**. Let $A \subset \mathbf{R}^{m},$ let $f: A \rightarrow \mathbf{R}^{n} .$ Suppose $A$ contains a neighborhood of a. We say that $f$ is differentiable at a if there is an $n$ by $m$ matrix $B$ such that
$$
\frac{f(\mathbf{a}+\mathbf{h})-f(\mathbf{a})-B \cdot \mathbf{h}}{|\mathbf{h}|} \rightarrow \mathbf{0} \quad \text { as } \quad \mathbf{h} \rightarrow \mathbf{0}
$$
The matrix $B$, which is unique, is called the derivative of $f$ at a $;$ it is denoted $D f(\mathbf{a}).$

> **Question.** Let $f: R^{m} \rightarrow R^{n}$ be defined by the equation
> $$
> f(x)=B \cdot x+b
> $$
> where $B$ is an $n$ by $m$ matrix, and $b \in R^{n}$. Show that $f$ is differentiable at $a.$

**My Answer**. Take $B=Df(x)$. Then when we apply the definition we get
$$
\frac{f(\mathbf{a}+\mathbf{h})-f(\mathbf{a})-B \cdot \mathbf{h}}{|\mathbf{h}|}=\frac {B \cdot \mathbf{h}-B \cdot \mathbf{h}} {|\mathbf{h}|}=0
$$

as $h\rightarrow 0.$

Therefore $f$ is differentiable at $a$.

**Can you check my answer? Thanks...**

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is correct.

$f(a+h)=B(a+h)+b=Ba+Bh+b$

$f(a)=Ba+b$.

Hence, $f(a+h)-f(a)=Bh$.

Therefore setting $Df(a)=B$ gives you the desired result.